# Download a file from GoogleDrive exportlinks

Tags: python, google-drive-api, python-requests

Trying to download a file directly using Python and the Google Drive API exportlinks response.

1. Suppose I have an export link like this:

   a) https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxxx&exportFormat=docx
2. To download this file, I simply paste it into the browser, and the file automatically downloads to my Downloads folder.
3. How do I do the same thing in Python?

   EX: module.download_file_using_url(https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxxx&exportFormat=docx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is a repost of [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

In Python 2, use urllib2 which comes with the standard library.

import urllib2 response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/') html = response.read()

This is the most basic way to use the library, minus any error handling. You can also do more complex stuff such as changing headers. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).